# c++ наследование не определен базовый класс

Tags: c++, наследование

Есть базовый класс:

```
class csymbol
{
public:
    enum_symbol_type type;
    enum_keywords kw;
    enum_operations op;
    string ident;
    cvalue value;
};
```

От него наследуется класс

```
class cvalue : public csymbol
{
public:
    const_types type;
    int cint;
    double creal;
    char cchar;
    string cstring;
    bool cbool;
};
```

При сборке получаю ошибку `Ошибка   C2504   csymbol: не определен базовый класс`. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: вангую, что не включил хедер базового класса в начало хедера наследника....

Comment: @Fat-Zer включил

Comment: Вопрос на засыпку: какой размер будут иметь экземпляры этих классов?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Конфигурация классов бессмысленна. Класс `csymbol` включает класс `cvalue` в качестве подобъекта, а класс `cvalue` включает класс `csymbol` в качестве подобъекта. Это невозможно, ибо представляет собой бесконечно рекурсивную структуру данных.

Угадываю, что вы устроили у себя в коде циклическое включение заголовочных файлов и, ожидаемо, получили эту ошибку.

Не пытайтесь создавать структуры данных с циклическим включением подобъектов - это невозможно. И не пытайтесь делать циклическое включение заголовочных файлов - это ничего не даст.

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте перед классами предварительные объявления:

```
class csymbol;
class cvalue;
```

Попробуйте вместо

```
cvalue value;
```

использовать

```
cvalue *value;
```

Вот этот код у меня скомпилировался:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#define const_types int

enum enum_symbol_type{a,b};
enum enum_keywords{c,d};
enum enum_operations{e,f};


class csymbol;
class cvalue;

class csymbol
{
public:
    enum_symbol_type type;
    enum_keywords kw;
    enum_operations op;
    string ident;
    cvalue* value;
};


class cvalue : public csymbol
{
public:
    const_types type;
    int cint;
    double creal;
    char cchar;
    string cstring;
    bool cbool;
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
 cvalue value;
 csymbol symbol;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: не помогает. даже если удалить `cvalue value;` из `csymbol`, то ошибка остается

Comment: @mtrfnv Предварительные объявления добавьте. У меня с указателем вместо переменной компилируется.